# Codeigniter form checkbox group validation without using jquery or javascript

Tags: php, codeigniter

Just want to validate with codeigniter if at least one of the following checkbox fields is checked (without using jquery or javascript). Please help me :)

```
             $data = array(
             'name'        => 'cat',
             'id'          => 'cat',
             'value'       => 'accept',
             'checked'     => FALSE,
             'style'       => 'margin:10px',
             );
             echo form_checkbox($data);
             echo form_label("Cat<br>","cat");

             $data = array(
             'name'        => 'dog',
             'id'          => 'dog',
             'value'       => 'accept',
             'checked'     => FALSE,
             'style'       => 'margin:10px',
             );
             echo form_checkbox($data);
             echo form_label("Dog<br>","dog"); 

             $data = array(
             'name'        => 'parrot',
             'id'          => 'parrot',
             'value'       => 'accept',
             'checked'     => FALSE,
             'style'       => 'margin:10px',
             );
             echo form_checkbox($data);
             echo form_label("Parrot<br>","parrot");
```

Comment: Do you mean using CI's form validation library? Or just a basic true/false result?

Comment: No difference. Just want to make it work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and easy way is a simple if statement to check for at least one of them.

```
if ($this->input->post('cat') || $this->input->post('dog') || $this->input->post('parrot'))
{
    $at_least_one_checked = true;
}
else
{
    $at_least_one_checked = false;
}
```